# Wxpython installation failed on Google Colab

Tags: pip, wxpython, google-colaboratory

I want to install wxpython package on Google Colab. I have run the following command on Google Colab in python notebook and received the following error. Can anybody suggest what I am missing to install wxpython on Google Colab

!pip install wxPython

```
Collecting wxPython
Downloading
```

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/8b/31267dd6d026a082faed35ec8d97522c0236f2e083bf15aff64d982215e1/wxPython-4.0.7.post2.tar.gz (68.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 68.9MB 52kB/s 
     Requirement already satisfied: 
    pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from wxPython) (4.3.0)

```
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from 
wxPython) (1.12.0)

Requirement already satisfied: 
numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from wxPython) (1.17.4)

 Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages 
 (from pillow->wxPython) (0.46)
```

Building wheels for collected packages: wxPython

Building wheel for wxPython (setup.py) ... error

ERROR: Failed building wheel for wxPython

Running setup.py clean for wxPython
   Failed to build wxPython
   Installing collected packages: wxPython
   Running setup.py install for wxPython ... error

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, 
  setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
 z3213grr/wxPython/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z3213grr/wxPython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-f7ov3ut6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER: It cant be done and makes no sense. Why again do you want to run wxPython in the cloud (where there is no desktop to show a GUI on)?

LONGER ANSWER: What is your specific usecase?

I would be completely surprised if:

- wxPython would be installable on Google Colab
- even if you would manage to install, wx would do anything useful for you

As Google Colab runs jupyter notebooks/kernels for you in the cloud, there is no desktop where you could show the wxPython GUI elements.

**EDIT1:** QUESTION:

What is a reasonable GUI for jupyter notebooks?

As jupyter notebooks **are a GUI by and in itself**, and a rather decent one, I would honestly **not** advise to use kernels to make a GUI, it will be rather brittle.

Look at [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html) and [voila](https://blog.jupyter.org/and-voil%C3%A0-f6a2c08a4a93). What it essentially does is starting up a kernel, running the content of a notebook ans strip all input cells, but you still can interact with the kernel using widgets.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, The prime reason to install wxpython is that I have made a user interface for transfer learning on spyder using wxpython, i wanted to save my work on google colab. however as you rightly mentioned that there is no point using wxpython on the cloud, I wonder can you suggest any other tool that can be used for the GUI development on the jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can accept my answer if it meets your acceptance criteria :)